# Need help understanding "the template code provided by Metamask for how we can detect to see if the user has Metamask installed"?

Tags: solidity, web3js, metamask, javascript, web3-providers

I'm going through an online Solidity Tutorial, and it shows me this:

> "Here's some template code provided by Metamask for how we can detect
> to see if the user has Metamask installed, and if not tell them
> they'll need to install it to use our app:"

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);

  } else {
    // Handle the case where the user doesn't have web3. Probably
    // show them a message telling them to install Metamask in
    // order to use our app.
  }

  // Now you can start your app & access web3js freely:
  startApp()

})
```

I don't understand what's happening between the statements 'if' and 'else'.

```
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined')
```

If I'm correct, I think this part above checks to see if the object 'web3' isn't 'undefined'.

```
web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
```

This above I'm feeling really unsure with.

What I understand:

→ A new object is being created, by use of the object constructor 'Web3()'.

→ Which then is assigned to the variable 'web3js'.

→ 'web3' is a global Javascript object that Metamask injects their web3 provider into (which is one of infura's providers/servers).

What I need help with:

→ I need an explanation on what exactly the constructor function 'Web3()' does, or where I can find further details about it on. I can't seem to find it!

→ I don't fully understand the argument "web3.currentProvider" entered in the constructor function. I understand that it refers to the web3 provider Metamask uses, but I only know this because it said just that in the lesson. Where can I verify this?

Comment: That's a ver outdated tutorial. I'd recommend to follow the official Metamask documentation https://docs.metamask.io/guide/getting-started.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Web3()` constructor establish a connection to a particular network (mainnet, ropsten,...) through a full node or public node provider(infura) or like here establish the connection through provider that metamask inject to you global `window` object

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there a documentation that I can read about the Web3() constructor on?

Comment: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3.html